# Binding, threads and winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

How do I bind a ProgressBar to a property of a class updated in another thread?

The following code example shows my first naive attempt. It doesn't work because I get runtime errors about cross thread communication. I think I need to use Invoke in some way, but I'm not sure how to do it with the Binding class.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

class ProgressForm : Form
{
    private ProgressBar pbProgress;

    public ProgressForm(ref LongOp lo)
    {
        Binding b = new Binding("Value", lo, "Progress");
        pbProgress = new ProgressBar();
        pbProgress.DataBindings.Add(b);
        this.Controls.Add(pbProgress);
    }
}

class Program : Form
{
    private Button btnStart;
    private LongOp lo;

    public Program()
    {
        lo = new LongOp();
        btnStart = new Button();

        btnStart.Text = "Start long operation";
        btnStart.Click += new EventHandler(btnStart_Click);

        this.Controls.Add(btnStart);
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressForm pf = new ProgressForm(ref lo);
        lo.DoLongOp();
        pf.ShowDialog();
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Program());
    }
}

class LongOp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int progress;

    public void DoLongOp()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run));
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Progress++;
        }
    }

    public int Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return progress;
        }

        set
        {
            progress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Progress");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String field)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(field));
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I bind a ProgressBar to a value updated in another thread?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** <strike>I've switched to using the ThreadedBinding implementation Mr. Gravell wrote and linked to.</strike> I'm still getting the cross thread exception though. Pressing "Break" in the exception dialog highlights the `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(field));` line as the line causing the exception.

What more do I need to change?

**EDIT:** Looks like Mr. Gravell's post has been removed. The ThreadedBinding implementation I mentioned can be found at the end of this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/69d671cd57a2c7ab/2f078656d6f1ee1f?pli=1

I've switched back to plain old Binding in the example for easier compilation by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think the cross-threading issues will make data-binding proper a bit too clumsy to use here, and probably more complexity than you need in any case -- the data only needs to be plumbed one way.

You could just replace the binding with an event handler like this:

```
private void ProgressPropertyChangedHandler(object sender,
                                            PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // fetch property on event handler thread, stash copy in lambda closure
    var progress = LongOp.Progress;

    // now update the UI
    pbProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => pbProgress.Value = progress));
}
```